# How to find link button name with row id in datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.Item.ItemIndex);
LinkButton lnkid = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lbutton");
```

** i need to find what is the link button name for row id 1 so that i can compare **
*i have a link button in my datalist (  )if user clicks that buttton ,i need to change button text name to (reset).

Now problem is when code reach (if condition) its works when page reload again its changing to ack

```
if (LinkButton1.Text == "Ack"){LinkButton1.Text"Reset";}else{LinkButton1.Tex= "Ack";})
```

so i decided to take row id of link button , by having that id i can change particularly*

Comment: Where is this code? Show more. Row Id 1 means first row or a row where an ID is 1? Show also the aspx code of the DataList.

Comment: .
i have a link button in my datalist ( <asp:LinkButton ID="lbutton" runat="server" Text="Ack" CommandName="lnkreset" CommandArgument="link"> )if user clicks that buttton ,i need to change button text name to (reset).


Now problem is when code reach (if condition) its works when page reload again its changing to ack


( if (LinkButton1.Text == "Ack")
{
LinkButton1.Text = "Reset";
}
else
{
LinkButton1.Text = "Ack";
}
)


so i decided to take row id of link button , by having that id i can change particularly